# ¿Cómo hacer una categorización en Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo un sistema en **Laravel 5.5**, pero no sé que código debo escribir en el **fichero de migración** para que me genere las tablas "publicadores" y "sensores" manteniendo ese tipo de relación que se puede observar en la siguiente imagen:

[image: M.E.R]

Nota: Ignoren las flechas con "N" que están alrededor, ya que son relaciones de tablas que están al lado, pero que he recortado en la imagen.

No tengo claro como sería el alta, quizás un formulario llamado **ALTA DE PUBLICADORES**, en donde se colocan los datos estado, vfirmware, nombre y fechaens y luego una lista desplegable con los distintos tipos que hay (en primera instancia solo exisitirá **sensores**) y si se selecciona sensores que pida fechabat.

Probablemente no entiendan nada, porque no sé expresarme correctamente, así que añado lo siguiente: Tengo que dar de altas publicadores, pero habrán varios tipos y cada uno debe guardar una información u otra, pero entre ellos comparten información ¿cómo hago esto en Laravel 5.5?

Comment: haz revisado la documentación de laravel?

Comment: obvio, no lo encontré: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations

Comment: te comento que por ejemplo yo al querer categorizar algun producto lo hago desde el modelo's no desde las migraciones

Comment: Suponemos que no usas mongoDB no? porque lo que describes es el caso básico por el que se usa este gestor. Igualmente si tienes un motor menos permisivo como mysql, simplemente ten atributos nullables en la misma u otra tabla (incluso pivot) y un campo tipo para saber que necesita cargar

Comment: ¿Desde el modelo?¿cómo se hace?. Uso mysql

Comment: @ManuelRobles sigo sin encontrar documentación al respecto :(

Comment: El modelo y migración con todos los atributos posibles. Los atributos que no sean comunes todos en nullable en la migración, y ademas añadir un campo tipo para distinguir cuales son necesarios en cada caso

Comment: esa es la solución más fácil jaja, no es una categorización xd

Comment: Es una categorización, si quieres la forma real y profesional es con bases de datos noSQL como mongoDB  como te dije antes, que te permite objetos con distintos atributos. También esta la opción de seguir por el lado malo en rendimiento (mysql) y usar tablas pivot para con atributos_publicaciones